# Problems with AJAX call and phonegap

Tags: ios, ajax, web-applications, cordova, ios-simulator

I am developing a webapp in javascript and then make it "native" with PhoneGap. In this application I need to export to PDF, and for that I use a PHP script via an AJAX call. In this PHP call, I send a large amount of information, including a huge table in html and two SVG strings, each representing a chart.

This is my AJAX call in javascript :

```
  jQuery.ajax(
    {
      type:'POST',
      url: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/php/pdfexport.php?callback=?',
      data:
      {
        dataHeader: JSON.stringify( tableHeaderEl ), //First table (Small)
        dataBody: JSON.stringify( tableBodyEl ), // Second table (Large)
        graphBar : JSON.stringify( svgBar ), // First chart (Large SVG)
        graphPie : JSON.stringify( svgPie ) // Second chart (Large SVG)
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success :
        function( result )
        {
          alert( 'Ok' );
        }
    }
  ).error(
    function( a, b, c )
    {
      alert( 'Error exporting PDF!' );
    }
  );
```

In PHP I dump the data received in a log file with the following code

```
<?php
  $log = fopen( 'temp\\log.txt', 'a' );  
  ob_start();
  var_dump ($_REQUEST);
  $data = ob_get_clean();
  fwrite($log, $data);
  fclose($log);
  $result = array
  (
    "success" => true,
  );
  echo $_REQUEST['callback'] . "(" . json_encode($result) . ")";
?>
```

With the application running directly in Safari I see the log with all the information sent, but from within the application created with PhoneGap, if a sent only the first table I see that the information is dumped, but if I send all the 4 strings, then nothing happens. No error also seems to be generated because the error function is not called.
I have looked for some response to someone with such a problem, but could not find anything.

Has anyone encountered such a problem?

I'm using xcode 4, PhoneGap 1.5 and jQuery 1.7.1.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
jQuery.ajax(
{
  type:'POST',
  url: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/php/pdfexport.php?callback=?',      
  data: JSON.stringify({ dataHeader: tableHeaderEl , dataBody:tableBodyEl , graphBar:svgBar ,graphPie : svgPie }),
  dataType: "json",
  success :
    function( result )
    {
      alert( 'Ok' );
    }
}
).error(
function( a, b, c )
{
  alert( 'Error exporting PDF!' );
}
);
```

Comment: I, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately had already tried that too, but with the same result.